# When I build ndk with .a files it comes like this `error adding symbols: File in wrong format`

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, .a

When I build ndk with .a files it comes like this `error adding symbols: File in wrong format`.

```
WORKING_DIR := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame
LOCAL_MODULE    := lame
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame \
                $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lame/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DSTDC_HEADERS -std=c99
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
APP_OPTIM := release

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := VbrTag.c \
               bitstream.c \
               encoder.c \
               fft.c \
               gain_analysis.c \
               id3tag.c \
               lame.c \
               mpglib_interface.c \
               newmdct.c \
               presets.c \
               psymodel.c \
               quantize.c \
               quantize_pvt.c \
               reservoir.c \
               set_get.c \
               tables.c \
               takehiro.c \
               util.c \
               vbrquantize.c \
               version.c


#include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

#include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#LOCAL_MODULE  := mp3lame_a
#LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := lame

#include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE) 

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH := $(WORKING_DIR)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ffmpeg
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_AV_CONFIG_H -std=c99 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -DSTDC_HEADERS -Wno-deprecated-declarations
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg-jni.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(WORKING_DIR)/libavcodec $(WORKING_DIR)/libavcodec/arm      $(WORKING_DIR)/libavformat $(WORKING_DIR)/libavutil $(WORKING_DIR)/libavutil/arm

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := lame

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lm -lz $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lib/libavformat.a $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lib/libavcodec.a $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lib/libavfilter.a $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lib/libavresample.a $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lib/libswscale.a $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lib/libavutil.a $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lib/libx264.a $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lib/libpostproc.a $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lib/libswresample.a $(WORKING_DIR)/../third_party/lib/libfdk-aac.a

APP_OPTIM := release

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

When I build ndk the error occurs

[image]

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.418]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\prade>d:

D:\>cd D:\Github\n

D:\Github\n>ndk-build
Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-16.
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:ffmpeg: non-system libraries in linker flags: jni/../third_party/lib/libavformat.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavcodec.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavfilter.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavresample.a jni/../third_party/lib/libswscale.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavutil.a jni/../third_party/lib/libx264.a jni/../third_party/lib/libpostproc.a jni/../third_party/lib/libswresample.a jni/../third_party/lib/libfdk-aac.a
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
Android NDK:     current module
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:ffmpeg: non-system libraries in linker flags: jni/../third_party/lib/libavformat.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavcodec.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavfilter.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavresample.a jni/../third_party/lib/libswscale.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavutil.a jni/../third_party/lib/libx264.a jni/../third_party/lib/libpostproc.a jni/../third_party/lib/libswresample.a jni/../third_party/lib/libfdk-aac.a
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
Android NDK:     current module
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:ffmpeg: non-system libraries in linker flags: jni/../third_party/lib/libavformat.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavcodec.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavfilter.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavresample.a jni/../third_party/lib/libswscale.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavutil.a jni/../third_party/lib/libx264.a jni/../third_party/lib/libpostproc.a jni/../third_party/lib/libswresample.a jni/../third_party/lib/libfdk-aac.a
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
Android NDK:     current module
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:ffmpeg: non-system libraries in linker flags: jni/../third_party/lib/libavformat.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavcodec.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavfilter.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavresample.a jni/../third_party/lib/libswscale.a jni/../third_party/lib/libavutil.a jni/../third_party/lib/libx264.a jni/../third_party/lib/libpostproc.a jni/../third_party/lib/libswresample.a jni/../third_party/lib/libfdk-aac.a
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
Android NDK:     current module
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : ffmpeg <= ffmpeg-jni.c
jni/ffmpeg-jni.c:248:16: warning: initializing 'const jbyte *' (aka 'const signed char *') with an expression of type
  'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
const jbyte *url = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, rtmp_url, NULL);
           ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/ffmpeg-jni.c:252:37: warning: passing 'const jbyte *' (aka 'const signed char *') to parameter of type
  'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
if (avio_open(&fmt_context->pb, url, URL_WRONLY) < 0) {
                                ^~~
jni/libavformat/avio.h:391:44: note: passing argument to parameter 'url' here
 int avio_open(AVIOContext **s, const char *url, int flags);
                                       ^
jni/ffmpeg-jni.c:257:48: warning: passing 'const jbyte *' (aka 'const signed char *') to parameter of type
  'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, rtmp_url, url);
                                           ^~~
jni/ffmpeg-jni.c:297:18: warning: initializing 'unsigned char *' with an expression of type 'jbyte *'
  (aka 'signed char *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
 unsigned char *yuv_data = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, yuv_image, 0);
             ^          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 jni/ffmpeg-jni.c:330:52: warning: passing 'unsigned char *' to parameter of type 'jbyte *' (aka 'signed char *')
  converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
 (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, yuv_image, yuv_data, 0);
                                               ^~~~~~~~
5 warnings generated.
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= VbrTag.c
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:263:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[0], 8u, 0xffu);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:265:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[1], 3u, 7);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:266:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[1], 1u, (gfp->out_samplerate < 16000) ? 0 : 1);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:267:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[1], 1u, gfp->version);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:268:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[1], 2u, 4 - 3);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:269:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[1], 1u, (!gfp->error_protection) ? 1 : 0);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:271:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[2], 4u, gfc->bitrate_index);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:272:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[2], 2u, gfc->samplerate_index);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:273:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[2], 1u, 0);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:274:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[2], 1u, gfp->extension);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:276:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[3], 2u, gfp->mode);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:277:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[3], 2u, gfc->mode_ext);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:278:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[3], 1u, gfp->copyright);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:279:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[3], 1u, gfp->original);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:280:5: warning: shifting a negative signed value is undefined
  [-Wshift-negative-value]
SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(buffer[3], 2u, gfp->emphasis);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:255:68: note: expanded from macro 'SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE'
#define SHIFT_IN_BITS_VALUE(x,n,v) ( x = (x << (n)) | ( (v) & ~(-1 << (n)) ) )
                                                            ~~ ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.c:421:23: warning: comparison of array 'pTagData->toc' not equal to a null
  pointer is always true [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
    if (pTagData->toc != NULL) {
        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~    ~~~~
16 warnings generated.
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= bitstream.c
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= encoder.c
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= fft.c
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= gain_analysis.c
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= id3tag.c
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= lame.c
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:603:13: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when
  argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
    if (EQ(gfp->compression_ratio, 0))
        ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:168:12: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
(fabs(a) > fabs(b)) \
       ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:603:13: note: use function 'abs' instead
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:168:12: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
(fabs(a) > fabs(b)) \
       ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:603:13: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when
  argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
    if (EQ(gfp->compression_ratio, 0))
        ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:170:23: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
: (fabs((a)-(b)) <= (fabs(b) * 1e-6f)))
                  ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:603:13: note: use function 'abs' instead
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:170:23: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
: (fabs((a)-(b)) <= (fabs(b) * 1e-6f)))
                  ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:1559:9: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when
  argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
if (NEQ(gfp->scale, 0) && NEQ(gfp->scale, 1.0)) {
    ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:175:20: note: expanded from macro 'NEQ'
#define NEQ(a,b) (!EQ(a,b))
               ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:168:12: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
(fabs(a) > fabs(b)) \
       ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:1559:9: note: use function 'abs' instead
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:175:20: note: expanded from macro 'NEQ'
#define NEQ(a,b) (!EQ(a,b))
               ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:168:12: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
(fabs(a) > fabs(b)) \
       ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:1559:9: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when
  argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
if (NEQ(gfp->scale, 0) && NEQ(gfp->scale, 1.0)) {
    ^
jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:175:20: note: expanded from macro 'NEQ'
#define NEQ(a,b) (!EQ(a,b))
               ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:170:23: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 : (fabs((a)-(b)) <= (fabs(b) * 1e-6f)))
                  ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:1559:9: note: use function 'abs' instead
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:175:20: note: expanded from macro 'NEQ'
 #define NEQ(a,b) (!EQ(a,b))
               ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:170:23: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 : (fabs((a)-(b)) <= (fabs(b) * 1e-6f)))
                  ^
  jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:1568:9: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when
   argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
 if (NEQ(gfp->scale_left, 0) && NEQ(gfp->scale_left, 1.0)) {
    ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:175:20: note: expanded from macro 'NEQ'
 #define NEQ(a,b) (!EQ(a,b))
               ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:168:12: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 (fabs(a) > fabs(b)) \
       ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:1568:9: note: use function 'abs' instead
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:175:20: note: expanded from macro 'NEQ'
 #define NEQ(a,b) (!EQ(a,b))
               ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:168:12: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 (fabs(a) > fabs(b)) \
       ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:1568:9: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when
  argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
 if (NEQ(gfp->scale_left, 0) && NEQ(gfp->scale_left, 1.0)) {
    ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:175:20: note: expanded from macro 'NEQ'
 #define NEQ(a,b) (!EQ(a,b))
               ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:170:23: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 : (fabs((a)-(b)) <= (fabs(b) * 1e-6f)))
                  ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:1568:9: note: use function 'abs' instead
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:175:20: note: expanded from macro 'NEQ'
 #define NEQ(a,b) (!EQ(a,b))
               ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:170:23: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 : (fabs((a)-(b)) <= (fabs(b) * 1e-6f)))
                  ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:1575:9: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when
  argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
 if (NEQ(gfp->scale_right, 0) && NEQ(gfp->scale_right, 1.0)) {
    ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:175:20: note: expanded from macro 'NEQ'
 #define NEQ(a,b) (!EQ(a,b))
               ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:168:12: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 (fabs(a) > fabs(b)) \
       ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:1575:9: note: use function 'abs' instead
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:175:20: note: expanded from macro 'NEQ'
 #define NEQ(a,b) (!EQ(a,b))
               ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:168:12: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 (fabs(a) > fabs(b)) \
       ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:1575:9: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when
  argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
 if (NEQ(gfp->scale_right, 0) && NEQ(gfp->scale_right, 1.0)) {
    ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:175:20: note: expanded from macro 'NEQ'
 #define NEQ(a,b) (!EQ(a,b))
               ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:170:23: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 : (fabs((a)-(b)) <= (fabs(b) * 1e-6f)))
                  ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/lame.c:1575:9: note: use function 'abs' instead
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:175:20: note: expanded from macro 'NEQ'
 #define NEQ(a,b) (!EQ(a,b))
               ^
 jni/ ../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:170:23: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 : (fabs((a)-(b)) <= (fabs(b) * 1e-6f)))
                  ^
 8 warnings generated.
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= mpglib_interface.c
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= newmdct.c
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= presets.c
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:145:5: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when
  argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
 SET_OPTION(quant_comp, set->quant_comp, -1);
 ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:36:16: note: expanded from macro 'SET_OPTION'
 else if (!(fabs(lame_get_##opt(gfp) - def) > 0)) \
           ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:145:5: note: use function 'abs' instead
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:36:16: note: expanded from macro 'SET_OPTION'
 else if (!(fabs(lame_get_##opt(gfp) - def) > 0)) \
           ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:146:5: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when
  argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
 SET_OPTION(quant_comp_short, set->quant_comp_s, -1);
 ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:36:16: note: expanded from macro 'SET_OPTION'
 else if (!(fabs(lame_get_##opt(gfp) - def) > 0)) \
           ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:146:5: note: use function 'abs' instead
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:36:16: note: expanded from macro 'SET_OPTION'
 else if (!(fabs(lame_get_##opt(gfp) - def) > 0)) \
           ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:259:5: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when
  argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
 SET_OPTION(quant_comp, abr_switch_map[r].quant_comp, -1);
 ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:36:16: note: expanded from macro 'SET_OPTION'
 else if (!(fabs(lame_get_##opt(gfp) - def) > 0)) \
           ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:259:5: note: use function 'abs' instead
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:36:16: note: expanded from macro 'SET_OPTION'
 else if (!(fabs(lame_get_##opt(gfp) - def) > 0)) \
           ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:260:5: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs' when
  argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
 SET_OPTION(quant_comp_short, abr_switch_map[r].quant_comp_s, -1);
 ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:36:16: note: expanded from macro 'SET_OPTION'
 else if (!(fabs(lame_get_##opt(gfp) - def) > 0)) \
           ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:260:5: note: use function 'abs' instead
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/presets.c:36:16: note: expanded from macro 'SET_OPTION'
 else if (!(fabs(lame_get_##opt(gfp) - def) > 0)) \
           ^
 4 warnings generated.
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= psymodel.c
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= quantize.c
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= quantize_pvt.c
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/quantize_pvt.c:664:23: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs'
  when argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
    while (k-- && EQ(xr[k], 0)) {
                  ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:168:12: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 (fabs(a) > fabs(b)) \
       ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/quantize_pvt.c:664:23: note: use function 'abs' instead
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:168:12: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 (fabs(a) > fabs(b)) \
       ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/quantize_pvt.c:664:23: warning: using floating point absolute value function 'fabs'
  when argument is of integer type [-Wabsolute-value]
    while (k-- && EQ(xr[k], 0)) {
                  ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:170:23: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 :  (fabs((a)-(b)) <= (fabs(b) * 1e-6f)))
                  ^
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/quantize_pvt.c:664:23: note: use function 'abs' instead
 jni/../third_party/lame/libmp3lame/machine.h:170:23: note: expanded from macro 'EQ'
 : (fabs((a)-(b)) <= (fabs(b) * 1e-6f)))
                  ^
 2 warnings generated.
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= reservoir.c
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= set_get.c
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= tables.c
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= takehiro.c
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= util.c
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= vbrquantize.c
 [arm64-v8a] Compile        : lame <= version.c
 [ arm64-v8a] StaticLibrary  : liblame.a
 [ arm64-v8a] SharedLibrary  : libffmpeg.so
 jni/../third_party/lib/libavformat.a: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
 clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 make: *** [D:/install/sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:725: obj/local/arm64-v8a/libffmpeg.so] Error 1

  D:\Github\n>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't see anything in your question about how you're building those third party libraries or where they come from. In any case, you're supposed to use `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` to specify static libraries to link against. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk and https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts

Comment: See the Android.mk file

Comment: Like I said, there are a bunch of libraries that you're referring to in your makefile, but you haven't shown how they were built or said anything about where they come from.

Comment: I build those .a files with ubuntu.

Comment: You need to build all of them using the NDK, and for all the ABIs you plan on supporting.

Comment: How can I create  .a files for all the ABIs ? Give a tutorial.

Comment: When build ffmpeg with x264 and fdk-AAC it only creates .so file and include folder. How can I create .a files?